# count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in Laravel 6 and php 7.2+

Tags: laravel-6, php-ini

```
print_r($user_data);
stdClass Object
(
[active_event_id] => 1
[id] => 2
[first_name] => Gayathree5r
[last_name] => Shirsat 4
[email] => delegate@gmail.com
[profile_pic] => front-end-assets/img/profiles/gayathree@gmaill.com.jpg
[dob] => 1970-01-01
[address] => 
[gender] => Female
[mobile] => 7815085581
[company] => Happiest Minds
[designation] => sdad designation 4r
)

if (count($user_data) === 0) {
 .....
}
```

When I apply count above object, it throws below error..
its working fine in local machine but not in digitalocean apache2 server.

> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in Laravel 6 and php 7.2+

Answer (score 0):

Count parameter accept only array. but it is a single record. so you have to use

```
if(is_object($user_data)){}
```